# Can't recognize third external display on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I am working on a Lenovo ThinkPad T480 with Ubuntu 18.04.

A few days ago everything was ok and it recognized 2 external displays.

For some reasons it recognizes only one now.

I did switching between them (physically + HDMI cables) - didn't help.
Reconfigured the light gdm, gdm3 ... - nothing.
Rebooted - nothing.

Please advise what should I do to force Ubuntu recognize the display.
Please share the commands and I will share the output.

[image]